# Awk Conditional Test Statement

Tags: awk

I would really appreciate some help. I spent almost the whole morning on it.

I have a data of structure field 1 to 16 as follows

```
4572 1307084940 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.28125 0.5 0.125 0.09375 0 0 0 0 0 0
4573 1307101627 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.6875 0.125 0.1875 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4574 1307101642 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.5625 0.25 0.03125 0.15625 0 0 0 0 0 0
4575 1307101662 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.53125 0.25 0.1875 0.03125 0 0 0 0 0 0
4576 1307127329 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.4375 0.34375 0.09375 0.125 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

From field 7 to 10 I need a test on the elements (ranging fro 0-1) and the field number.
i.e. for every record, check the fields 7-10 for maximum value,

if found and its in field 7 print $0, $6-4
if found and its in field 8 print $0, $6-3
if found and its in field 9 print $0, $6-2
if found and its in field 10 print $0, $6-1

I'll be so grateful for the help. Thank you in advance

**Edit (by belisarius)**

Just transcripting a comment from @Tumi2002  (author)

Sorry, my 6th field (i.e. $6) has values 1-5.
I am trying to reclassify records where field 6=5 back into 1-4 classes in the same fieid).
So that instead of 5 classes I have 4.

```
Awk '$6==5 
{for i=7; i<11; i++) 
 if ($i==max) && NF==7)  print $0,$6-4;
 if ($i==max) && NF==8)  print $0,$6-3;
 if ($i==max) && NF==9)  print $0,$6-2; 
 if ($i==max) && NF==10) print $0,$6-1
```

I am struggling with the syntax in awk

Comment: You may edit the question to ease reading ...

Comment: Sorry, my 6th field (i.e. $6) has values 1-5. I am trying to reclassify records where field 6=5 back into 1-4 classes in the same fieid). So that instead of 5 classes I have 4. Awk '$6==5 {for i=7; i<11; i++) if ($i==max) && NF==7) print $0,$6-4; if ($i==max) && NF==8) print $0,$6-3; if ($i==max) && NF==9) print $0,$6-2; if ($i==max) && NF==10) print $0,$6-1

Comment: I am struggling with the syntax in awk

Comment: edit your question instead of posting comments that modify its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
 max=0; maxindex=0;
 for (i=7; i<=10; i++)
 {
  if ($i>max){
          maxindex=i;
          max=$i;
          # print i;
         }
 }
 if (maxindex > 0){
         print $6-11+maxindex;
         }
}
```

Running at [ideone](http://ideone.com/clone/JHumV)

Output for your example data:

```
2
1
1
1
1
```

**Edit**

Modified answering your comment:

```
($6 == 5){
       max=0; maxindex=0;
       for (i=7; i<=10; i++)
       {
        if ($i>max){
          maxindex=i;
          max=$i;
          # print i;
        }
       }
       if (maxindex > 0){
         print $0,"-->",$6-11+maxindex;
          }
 }
```

Output:

```
4572 1307084940 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.28125 0.5 0.125 0.09375 0 0 0 0 0 0 --> 2
4573 1307101627 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.6875 0.125 0.1875 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --> 1
4574 1307101642 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.5625 0.25 0.03125 0.15625 0 0 0 0 0 0 --> 1
4575 1307101662 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.53125 0.25 0.1875 0.03125 0 0 0 0 0 0 --> 1
4576 1307127329 RDCSWE 2006 1 5 0.4375 0.34375 0.09375 0.125 0 0 0 0 0 0 --> 1
```

Running at ideone [here](http://ideone.com/clone/ack8V)

Comment: @Zsolt yep. For short code snippets it is wonderful. I also learned about it in SO. Glad to spread the word.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm!!! I am very sorry for the mess. I was just getting too desperate. You saved my day. I just need to make 1 minor edit on instances where i have 0.5 0.5. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for [belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353410/belisarius) for pointing to [ideone](http://ideone.com/).

My (updated) solution is [working correctly now](http://ideone.com/3OGSR):

```
# max value in an array, copied verbatim from the gawk manual (credit)
function maxelt(vec,   i, ret)
 {
      for (i in vec) {
           if (ret == "" || vec[i] > ret)
                ret = vec[i]
      }
      return ret
 }

# Load all fields of each record into nums.
{
     delete nums
     for(i = 7; i <= 10; i++)
          { nums[NR, i] = $i }
     ### DEBUG print NR, maxelt(nums)
     if ( $7 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-4) } 
     if ( $8 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-3) } 
     if ( $9 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-2) } 
     if ( $10 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-1) } 
}
```

HTH

Comment: function maxelt(vec,   i, ret)
 {
      for (i in vec) {
           if (ret == "" || vec[i] > ret)
                ret = vec[i]
      }
      return ret
 }

 # Load all fields of each record into nums.
 {
      for(i = 7; i <= 10; i++)
           { nums[NR, i] = $i }
      if ( $7 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-4) }
      if ( $7 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-3) }
      if ( $7 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-2) }
      if ( $7 == maxelt(nums) ) { print $0, ($6-1) }
 } sample.dat > test.dat2

Comment: I have a syntax error on 2 lines ./class.sh: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `vec,'
./class.sh: line 43: `function maxelt(vec,   i, ret)'

Comment: Could you please use gist.github.com for code pastes (in the comment files)? And tell us what version of awk are you using?

Comment: I got code for the solution. Thanks for the gist.github.com tip. I'll keep that in mind next time.